# two gateways / two providers with different ips

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, gateway

I want to route packets coming in on eth0 back over eth0 and the ones coming in to eth1 back over eth1. I don't care which gateway is used for outgoing connections.

If i just enter two gateways in /etc/network/interfaces then the kernel routes packets out on both interfaces.

I remember it has something to do with routing tables but I don't know how to do it/where can I read more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve is multi-homing, not bonding or load-balancing.

To do this you'll need to implement what is known as "policy" or "source based" routing.

Which you can do in Linux by using the [`iproute2`](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Net:Iproute2) package.

There is a good article that explains how to, [here](http://www.clintoneast.com/articles/multihomed.php).

Comment: This just solved about 3 hrs of banging my head against a brick wall.  "Why arn't packets coming back...... disable rp_filter"  Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for in http://serverfault.com/questions/567487/iptables-packet-forwarding-to-one-of-two-gateways-depending-on-origin/567515. Unfortunately, the link is broken :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a working MultiISP setup using shorewall based on this answer: [NIC bonding with two uplinks](https://serverfault.com/questions/30549/nic-bonding-with-two-uplinks/30602#30602)

It easy to implement and manage, works well in a "load balancing" configuration, where packets are evenly distributed between uplinks if no cached routes are found.

Read more about it here: http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html

Comment: Ok, thanks I don't need load balancing but it should work so I'll try that.

Comment: No problem. Although raw iproute2 solutions are ok, having shorewall gives you a very nice abstraction and less maintenance problems for acomplishing the same task.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/) web page describing exactly how to achieve this using iptables2.

I found it using google and "linux 2 default gateways"