# Configure a web server with two gateways

Tags: networking, gateway, netplan

I have two routers: Router 1 and Router 2 both connected to the internet. A desktop computer (lets name webserver) serving some websites is connected to both routers. Router 1 through WiFi and Router 2 through ethernet. I have a setup using dydns server which points a certain URL (call `super.com`) to the Router 1. The router has port configured so that it sends any request to the webserver. Since the webserver is connected to both routers, how can I configure the web server so that it can serve my website request coming from Router 1 but also let me use Router 2 for other internet surfing? I can simplify the case as in the figure below.

I saw the related question [Here](https://serverfault.com/q/44478), but I could not tie together with my problem.

[image]

Comment: `let me use Router 2 for other internet surfing?` - Why are you wanting to "surf the internet" from the web server? Why are you using a desktop computer as a server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
this is asymetric routing. and it will fail for two reasons:

- You are using NAT (your router translate public IP to private
  adresses)
- You have different public IPs on each router

If you want to serve content to the internet. Your webserver must have one route to the internet.