# How do I set up the default route on a Linux router with dual ISP links?

Tags: iptables, routing, multipath, multi-homed

So, here's the situation.

I have dual ISP links currently active and working for routing traffic from my network, with a very similar iptables setup to the accepted answer at [Load balancing & NAT-ing multiple ISP connections on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/93678/load-balancing-nat-ing-multiple-isp-connections-on-linux)

I've got two lines in my `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` that look like:

```
...
10 COMCAST
20 CENTURYLINK
...
```

I set up the routes in each table with the proper default gateway, and set up the rules like so:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table COMCAST prio 33000
ip rule add fwmark 2 table CENTURYLINK prio 33000
```

And then I set up iptables-based packet marking and routing:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK restore
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match ! 0x0
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK set 0x1
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode random probability 0.33300000010 MARK set 0x2
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK save
```

The problem is, if I leave the system-wide default route (as in `ip route list` with no `table` arguments) in place for either ISP, it seems like that overrides the `iptables` routing for client machines - no packets go over the non-default connection, according to `watch -n 1 ifconfig [interface]`. If I delete the system-wide default route, routing works great for all of my client machines, with 33%-ish of the packets going over the CenturyLink line, and the rest over the Comcast line. This is awesome!

However, not having a default route breaks everything that needs an internet connection on the router itself. I can't run `apt-get update` on the router, for example. So, how do I set up a default route for the system that won't override the `iptables` routing setup? I attempted to set up the multipath route according to the LARTC site's instructions like so:

```
ip route add default scope global nexthop via $P1 dev $IF1 weight 1 nexthop dev $IF2 weight 1
```

(I had to slightly modify from the LARTC guide, because the CenturyLink connection's default route doesn't have a gateway IP, just `dev ppp0`, and it works for that table's default gateway.)

But the multipath route breaks everything on the server AND the clients that it's routing for. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out on my own.

The solution, in case anybody else runs into a similar situation, was to alter the priority of the `ip rule` entries for fwmark. I didn't read [lbt's answer to the related question](https://serverfault.com/a/584764/20945) carefully enough; he specifically points out that setting the priority to 33000 will make these rules take place *after* the `default` table lookup, which is the opposite of what I want. So, I altered the rules to look like this:

```
100:    from all fwmark 0x1 lookup COMCAST
100:    from all fwmark 0x2 lookup CENTURYLINK
```

And now, having a default route doesn't break the firewall-based routing, and I can run `apt-get` and all of my other programs without any issues. Hooray!